# 3d FBX file import into Unity not working as expected

Tags: unity-game-engine, maya, virtual-reality

I am interested in building virtual reality applications and I am at beginner level.

I imported a FBX file of Airplane and imported it in Unity,
Upon linking the animation in Unity and building it onto my Mobile, I see a 2D version of the model. How should I convert it into virtual reality application.

Below is a snalshot of the file. The aiation is also fairly simple, one plane takes off and flies for sometime before landing.

[image]
Below is a snapshot of the Game Console
[image]
So inshort the question is how do I convert this into a 3D mode so that I can use it as a virtual reality Application.

Thank you

Comment: I see no images? Tell us what you are seeing and what you are expecting to see so we can answer.

Comment: I have uploaded the image now, I want to build a VR application and I am using a 3D model built in Maya

Answer (score 1):

That is 3D mode.

Making a VR application isn't done at the push of a button

Start here:
[Read about VR in unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality)

**It seems like you are a new Unity user. If so do this first:**

Depending on what you want to do in your application you should look into the Unity Documentation and read about:

- [Basics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityBasics.html)
- [Cameras](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CamerasOverview.html)
- [Creating Gameplay](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingGameplay.html)
- [Animation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationSection.html)

If you at some point feel you don't understand these links, you may need to take another step back and start off by checking out [the official tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials)

Comment: thanks @Oscar, one more question, where does Maya3D or Blender come into picture if I intend to make good 3D VR scene of an airplane, or an apartment

Answer (score 0):

Just save your **.blend** file in the Unity's **Assets** folder.

Look at the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectBlender.html) for more informations